# Apache Cross Compilation Error ./gen_test_char: cannot execute binary file

Tags: c++, apache, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

I looked quite some time to find a solution to this bug.  When trying to Cross-Compile Apache for an Arm (I am sure that this could happen for many other Architectures), I would get this bug from with in the server folder:

```
 ./gen_test_char: cannot execute binary file
```

This means that Apache is trying to compile this test_char.h generator for the actual device while I need it to run on my Ubuntu where I am Cross-Compiling.  Ubuntu does not recognize the compiled gen_test_char as an executable so I need to get it compiled correctly for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched and searched and found several tries to patch but none of them worked.  Most of these were patches suggested directly from the Apache dev group.

But I finally came across this [Apache mail list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201203.mbox/%3C4F646F05.80302@apache.org%3E).  It suggests a straight forward solution that the patches could not provide.

Compile the gen_test_char app before trying to cross-compile Apache.  So I did.  And followed the suggestions and it worked like a charm.

> instead just compile gen_test_char.c 1st with something like:
>   gcc -Wall -O2 -DCROSS_COMPILE gen_test_char.c -s -o gen_test_char
>   then run it and put its output into the include folder (or where its 
>   placed normaly);

and after this compilation run it to get the desired output with:

```
 ./gen_test_char > test_char.h
```

Comment: I had to copy the `test_char.h` to `apr-1.6.5/include/private/apr_escape_test_char.h` for `make` to succeed

Answer (score 1):

These are specific steps that worked for me based off of the [Apache Mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201203.mbox/%3C4F646F05.80302@apache.org%3E) that CaptainBli linked in his answer. I am cross-compiling for ARM from an x86_64 machine.

First, configure and run make for cross-compilation. Once the compilation fails due to the gen_test_char executable issue, go into the `tools/` folder and re-compile gen_test_char for your build system:

```
$ pwd
.../apr-1.7.0
$ cd tools/
$ gcc -Wall -O2 -DCROSS_COMPILE gen_test_char.c -s -o gen_test_char
```

Now, run `make` as you did previously and it will start where it left off, except this time it will use the `gen_test_char` executable that is built to run on your build system. **Do not** run `make clean` first - that will wipe out the executable you just built and you will be back to square one.