# Cross compile ActiveMQ for ARM

Tags: c++, linux, apache, arm, activemq-classic

**Disclaimer:** I am new here, I've done my best to follow the posting guidelines so please let me know if this needs any extra information. I am also relatively new to Linux development.

**Background:**
I am in the process of building a library using ActiveMQ-cpp on Linux. I have built and run it successfully on the host Ubuntu PC, but attempting to cross-compile it for the target ARM-based machine is producing some very abstruse errors.

The first step involves building APR (http://apr.apache.org/) using the arm-linux-gcc compiler. After some research, the following command runs the configuration script with little fuss:

```
CC=/usr/local/arm-linux/bin/arm-linux-gcc ./configure --prefix=/root/apr-arm --host=arm-linux cross_compiling=yes ac_cv_file__dev_zero=no ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=no apr_cv_tcp_nodelay_with_cork=no apr_cv_process_shared_works=no
```

This allows the next step - running the makefile.

**Current Issue:** Entering make on the command line exits prematurely at the following line:

```
[...]
/root/.local/share/Trash/files/apr-1.5.1/build/mkdir.sh include/private
tools/gen_test_char > include/private/apr)escape_test_char.h
/bin/bash: tools/gen_test_char: cannot execute binary file
make[1]: *** [include/private/apr_escape_test_char.h] Error 126
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.local/share/Trash/files/apr-1.5.1'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

**Attempted Fixes:** A solution to the following question, posted by the asker, has not worked. It is possible that I've not followed the process correctly ([Apache Cross Compilation Error ./gen_test_char: cannot execute binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408400/apache-cross-compilation-error-gen-test-char-cannot-execute-binary-file))

In the same theme, I tried temporarily removing the problem gen_test_char program from its directory but the clever script just rebuilds it.

My aim is to either avoid this error and continue the build process on Ubuntu, or perhaps consider other means of building the library. I have built it with no trouble in VS2013 on Windows, so if it is possible to cross compile that project for ARM architectures I would happily go ahead with that.

Answer (score 0):

APR need **gen_test_char** to be compiled for system not for arm, why you got "**bin/bash: tools/gen_test_char: cannot execute binary file**" error because make program is going to execute **gen_test_char** on your system and if you cross compile then every time you got this error.

To avoid this error please follow below steps:

```
1) Cross compile APR which is going to fail
2) compile APR for system and copy gen_test_char to cross compiled APR's directory.
3) Again cross compile
```

After performing above steps you should not get "cannot execute binary file" error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cross compile APR which is going to fail
2. compile APR for system and copy gen_test_char to cross compiled APR's directory.
3. change the name of gen_test_char to gen_test_char_host
4. in Makefile file change the name of gen_test_char to gen_test_char_host because make creates it again.
5. Again cross compile
   you may see some struct redefinition which needs to find the file and comment the redefined struct manually.